# How to ensure the better organisation and availability of knowledge on TeX.SX?

Tags: discussion, search

TEX.SX is a source of knowledge such as online encyclopedia (i.e. WP) but experts focus on (question/answer model). The issue facing online encyclopedia is how to get one source of knowledge available for a wide audience.

AFAIK, the only way to have access to old posts in TEX.SX is to use the search engine. This tool is powerful, with advanced options, **but** it is not sufficient. Indeed, people use to consult only the 5-10 first results (like in google). Lots of questions are not very accessible (because the asker does not use the correct `tag/keywords`, because the title of the question is formulated in such way it is not easy to find it, ...). I preferred sometimes to have a list of question by subjects (like in [some faq](http://www.grappa.univ-lille3.fr/FAQ-LaTeX/)). For example :

- `Biblatex`

  - creating your own style

    - question 1
    - question 2
    - question 3

In parallel to the search engine, is there a repository of questions by `tag/themes`? Should we create one (perhaps with only popular/well noted questions ?

Comment: I don't follow: you can search by tag and then by text within tags already.

Comment: See [help on searching](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for all the possible ways to search on multiple conditions.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes but it is not a LaTeX faq by subjects. I have precised my question

Comment: We do already have a meta question that points to a bunch of common questions, arranged by topic.  This is community wiki, so it can be added to by anyone. [Often referenced questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2419)

Comment: Related [Using search effectively](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2970/15717) but with no exact answer. Werner's [Tricks for Search](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3933/15717) and Some [of mine](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3450/15717)

Comment: First ingredient: _Search Patience_ and then exploit `TAG`-power like [big-list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list), [tutorials](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials) and [faq](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) which does not need even tags. Wiki-type-knowledge-bank-of-TeX.SX: [Often referenced questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2419/15717) and  [Collecting FAQ on LaTeX in this site into a recipe book that is collaberatively developed by us](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1642/15717)

Comment: "Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?"
"That depends a good deal on where you want to get to," said the Cat.
"I don’t much care where..." said Alice.
"Then it doesn’t matter which way you go," said the Cat.
(from "Alice in Wonderland") `:)`